# How to read or open a session file of Firefox Session Manager add-on

Tags: firefox, session-restore, session-manager

I have some *.session files from my previous Firefox from my previous PC that are very important to me.

I installed Firefox and Session Manager on my new PC, and copied those files to the respective folder (`%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\yhzy90ql.default\sessions`), but unfortunately the new session manager couldn't load them in its list. I tried to open a *.session file in Visual Studio, but nothing useful happened, so I have two related questions:

1. How is it possible to open some session files that are manually copied in the default location by the session manager?
2. What kind of tools or software except for session manager can open a session file?

Comment: Have you tried a simple text editor (like Notepad)?

Comment: of course I tried Notepad but what I saw was an encoded unreadable file and nothing more , in fact these files are   recovered files from an accidentally deletion , some of them are readable by Notepad and one of them is not and its very important for me :( the question is why session manager couldn't open those session files that are readable  by Notepad?

Comment: Can one provide such a *sessions* file? Maybe base64 encoded?

Answer (score 0):

.session files of Firefox or other web browsers is XML markup encoded in binary I think... Not exactly sure but this Python script should get you what you want:

```
   import pickle

   with open("PATH_TO_SESSION_FILE", "rb") as i:
        data = pickle.load(i)
        print(data)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```print(data)``` instead of ```print(i)```? Have you verified your answer works?

Comment: You are correct. I fixed the small mistake. My answer works on computer but I can show an example to prove so.